# Raising pythonic exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-3.5

Python 3.5.1..
I have some code which I need to use to raise an exception. I want to know if this is the 'pythonic' way of doing it. I have been told elsewhere that I should be using try/except, however, in this instance, I have been specifically instructed to use:

- if:raise /else
- LocationError must take one input, location
- LocationError must inherit from the Exception class

Given these restrictions, is there a 'better' way to do it?

```
location = [1, 2]

def update_loc(oldloc, newloc):
    if oldloc == newloc:
        raise LocationError('Location match, old location = {0}'.format(newloc))
    else:
        oldloc = newloc
    return oldloc

class LocationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, location):
        self._location = location #initial code
        super().__init__(location) #fixed code

location = update_loc(location, [1, 2])
```

So, the problem, I have been told, is that I was not inheriting from the Parent class, (Exception). I guess the point of creating a subclass for the exception was just that, nothing more.

Comment: Your string formatting is occurring in the wrong place.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were told that you should be using try/except but should be raising an exception here. One of those raises, the other catches. That's like saying you should be fundamentally returning a value, but in this case your function needs to take an argument. Raising exceptions is totally fine, as is catching them.

Comment: Where should it be occuring, I am asking because I wrote this based on examples that I have read, but something feels wrong about it.

Comment: Wayne do you mean something like `e = LocationError(newloc)` `raise e`

Comment: I'd consider making your custom exception extend something more specific, like [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). Note that the docs say "raised when a built-in ..." but this doesn't mean you can't extend it (or just use it) yourself; the docs are explaining when _Python_ will raise this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *totally* clear from your description, but I *suspect* that you need to

1. Define the LocationError exception class,
2. Raise that exception in your `update_loc` function if there's a location match, and
3. Call `update_loc` inside a `try..except` block to catch the exception.

Here's some code that does just that.

```
class LocationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

def update_loc(oldloc, newloc):
    if oldloc == newloc:
        raise LocationError(newloc)
    return newloc

location = [1, 2]

for data in ([1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2]):
    try:
        location = update_loc(location, data)
        print('New location = {0}'.format(location))
    except LocationError as e:
        print('LocationError: new location matches old location = {0}'.format(e.location))
```

**output**

```
LocationError: new location matches old location = [1, 2]
New location = [3, 4]
LocationError: new location matches old location = [3, 4]
New location = [1, 2]
```

---

Note that there's no point in assigning to `oldloc` in `update_loc`: that merely creates a new list that's local to `update_loc`. However, because these locations are lists it *is* possible to mutate them inside a function.

Eg, you can do

```
def update_loc(oldloc, newloc):
    if oldloc == newloc:
        raise LocationError(newloc)
    oldloc[:] = newloc

location = [1, 2]

for data in ([1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2]):
    try:
        update_loc(location, data)
        print('New location = {0}'.format(location))
    except LocationError as e:
        print('LocationError: new location matches old location = {0}'.format(e.location))
```

which will produce the same output as the earlier code.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the first instance, which I have updated. I was told by a more knowledgeable friend that I should be using try/except, however my class instruction is to use if, raise/else. Edit: only need to do the first two, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confusing some concepts. Generally exception handling defines how you handle situations where you try to do something that is not possible. In python you raise an exception which you can except and handle it.

```
i = input("Give me a number")
try:
    # the following line will raise an ZeroDivisionError
    print(5/i)
except ZeroDivisonError:
    print("You can't insert 0")
```

You can also manually raise Exceptions/Errors if you detect an erroneous state:

```
class Person

    def __init__(self, age):
        if age < 0:
            raise ValueError("Age can't be below zero")
```

There isn't really another way to raise an exception.

But there are multiple ways to handle exception. The first is to prevent them as much as you can (look before you leap, called LBYL).

```
age = input("What is your age?")
if age < 0:
    print("You can't be of a negative age.")
    exit(1)
person = Person(age)
```

Or you can simply try to do what you want and catch any exceptions later:

```
age = input("What is your age?")
try:
    person = Person(age)
except ValueError:
    print("You can't be of a negative age.")
```

This is generally called "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (called EAFP).

In python generally EAFP is preferred.